# Why does my overlap-add integrator in frequency domain result in distorted signals?

Tags: frequency-domain, integration, distortion

With help from [the dsp guide](http://www.dspguide.com/ch17/1.htm) and [DSP-Related](http://www.dsprelated.com/dspbooks/sasp/Example_Overlap_Add_Convolution.html), I tried to implement a leaky integrator in octave/matlab. It seems to work in general, but there are a few problems.

So that's what I do:

1. Calculate the optimal integrator (1/jω, damping below *fc* Hz) in the frequency domain
2. Band limit this filter (using custom_filter.m)
3. Apply the overlap-add method

The result can be seen in the images Fig 1 to Fig 4. As Fig 3 shows, the band limiter makes a linear phase shift from the desired constant phase shift, due to shift in time domain (see custom_filter.m). So my integrator isn't working, because the phase shift is wrong.

**There's an explanation in the update below the code**

[image: No distortion, wrong phase response]

If I undo the shift in time domain, I get a filter that looks quite good (phase shift is at least constant...), but the resulting signal looks very distorted (second image).

[image: Distortion, but better phase response]

So where does this distortion come from? And more important, how can I avoid it?

So here's the code. I was hoping I could attach it as a zip but couldn't find how...

```
clear;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Helper functions, used below. All in one file to copy and paste it
% to stackexchange.
%

#
#  y = spec_integrate( f, fc )
#  Integrates the f Hz line of a complex spectrum
#  with a fc Hz highpass
#
function y=spec_integrator(f, fc)
  if f==0,
    y=0;
  else
    y=1* 1000/( i * 2*pi*f );

    # attenuate at f < fc
    if f < fc,
      d=(f/fc)^2;
    else
      d=1;
    end
    y = y*d;
  end
endfunction;

%
% y = ccmirror( x ) "complex conjugate mirror" where:
%
% length( x ) = 2^N
% x contains the positive frequencies of a spectrum
% x(1    )   is DC
% x(N/2+1)   is the folding frequency
% x((N/2+2):N) is ignored
%
% y is created from x so that its negative frequencies y((N/2+2):N)
% are the complex conjugate of the positive frequencies.
%
% This means imag(ifft( y ) ) = 0
%
function y = ccmirror( x )
   N=length(x);
   y = x;
   y((N/2+2):N) = conj(y((N/2):-1:2));
endfunction;

%
% [impulse_response actual_frequency_response] = custom_filter( desired_frequency_response, M)
%
% Band limit a filter that has been customized in frequency domain
%
% desired_frequency_response is the custom filter definition
% M is the size of the filter kernel / impulse response
%
% impulse_response is the bandlimited impulse response, for
%                  informational purpose.
% actual_frequency_response is the bandlimited frequency response
%
% This is taken from [DSP-Related][2]
%
function [impulse_response actual_frequency_response] = custom_filter( desired_frequency_response, M)

  N=length(desired_frequency_response);
  %
  % Get the aliased impulse response
  %
  impulse_response=ifft( desired_frequency_response );
  %
  % Rotate the signal M/2 points to the right
  % Note: translation in time domain means a phase shift in frequency
  % domain! The phase of the frequency response is modified!
  %
  impulse_response=circshift( impulse_response, [0,M/2] );

  %
  % Truncate and window the signal
  %
  impulse_response=impulse_response .* [ hanning(M)' zeros(1,N-M)];

  %% One could undo the phase shift from above ... but it gives ugly
  %% results. Why?
  %% impulse_response=circshift( impulse_response, [0,-M/2] );

  actual_frequency_response=fft(impulse_response);
endfunction;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Now comes the more interesting stuff
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Set up simulation parameters

L = 1024;                                 % FIR filter length in taps
fc = 10;                                  % lowpass cutoff frequency in Hz
fs = 4000;                                % sampling rate in Hz

Nsig = 8192;                               % signal length in samples
fsig = 159;                               % Frequency of the demo signal
asig = 1;                                 % Amplitude of the demo signal

%FFT processing parameters:

M = L;                                    % nominal window length
Nfft = 2^(ceil(log2(M+L-1)));             % FFT Length
M = Nfft-L+1;                             % efficient window length
R = M;                                    % hop size for rectangular window
Nframes = 1+floor((Nsig-M)/R);            % no. complete frames

lc = round(fc * Nfft/fs);                 % line of the corner frequency

% Generate the test signal:

sig = asig * sin( 2 * pi * (0:(Nsig-1)) * fsig/fs );

% Define the filter in frequency domain

%
% integrator
%
H = zeros( 1, Nfft );
for f = 1:(Nfft/2+1)
  H(f) = spec_integrator( (f-1) *fs/Nfft, fc );
end
H = ccmirror( H );

Hoptimal = H;

[impulse_response Hactual] = custom_filter( Hoptimal, L);
H = Hactual;


% Carry out the overlap-add FFT processing:

y = zeros(1,Nsig + Nfft);                 % allocate output+'ringing' vector
for m = 0:(Nframes-1)
    index = m*R+1:min(m*R+M,Nsig);        % indices for the mth frame
    xm = sig(index);                      % windowed mth frame (rectangular window)
    xmzp = [xm zeros(1,Nfft-length(xm))]; % zero pad the signal
    Xm = fft(xmzp);
    Ym = Xm .* H;                         % freq domain multiplication
    ym = real(ifft(Ym));                  % inverse transform
    outindex = m*R+1:(m*R+Nfft);
    y(outindex) = y(outindex) + ym;       % overlap add
end

f=(0:(Nfft-1))*fs/Nfft;                   % frequencies for plotting
tin=(0:(length(sig)-1))/fs;               % times for plotting

figure 1 % input
clf
plot( tin, sig );
hold on;
for m = 1:Nframes
  plot( [ m*L m*L ]/fs, [ min(sig), max(sig) ], "r");
end
ylabel('Amplitude')
xlabel('Time/s')
title( "Fig 1: Input signal")
legend( sprintf("%g Hz", fsig), "Overlap-Add-Frames");

figure 2 % transfer function (abs)
clf
loglog( f, abs(H), "r" );
hold on;
loglog( f, abs(Hoptimal));
hold off;
ylabel('Amplitude')
xlabel('Frequency/Hz')
title( "Fig 2: Filter magnitude")
legend( "Band limited", "Optimal");

figure 3 % transfer function (phase)
clf
plot( f, unwrap(arg(H)), "r" );
hold on;
plot( f, unwrap(arg(Hoptimal)));
hold off;
ylabel('Phase/rad')
xlabel('Frequency/Hz')
title( "Fig 3: Filter phase")
legend( "Band limited", "Optimal");

tout=(0:(length(y)-1))/fs;

figure 4 % result
clf
plot( tout, y );
hold on;
plot( [ L/2 L/2 ]/fs, [ min(y) max(y) ], "r");
plot( [ L L ]/fs, [ min(y) max(y) ], "r");
plot( [ length(y)-Nfft length(y)-Nfft ]/fs, [ min(y) max(y) ], "r" )
plot( [ length(y)-Nfft-L/2 length(y)-Nfft-L/2 ]/fs, [ min(y) max(y) ], "r" )
plot( [ length(y)-Nfft-L length(y)-Nfft-L ]/fs, [ min(y) max(y) ], "r" )
hold off;
ylabel('Amplitude')
xlabel('Time/s')
title( "Fig 4: Filtered signal")
legend( sprintf("%g Hz", fsig), sprintf( "L/2=%d samples / %gs", L/2, L/2/fs));
```

**Update**

Ok, so I was thinking a bit about the phase response in image 1, Figure 3: The bandlimiter shifts the signal in time domain, which means a change of the gradient of the phase response. That's what we see in Figure 3. I've been unsettled by this because I didn't know what this means for my integrator.
But then I went on and thought about the group delay. The derivative of my phase response is constant, so there is a constant group delay which just means that the time domain signal is shifted by a constant value - which is just what the bandlimiter did :) So the integrator is in fact working and to be exact I'd have to shift the final signal back to where it belongs.

Great, so now I think the integrator works. Now only one thing is left: *why is the result distorted when I undo the time shift of the bandlimiter?*

Comment: Markus:"So the integrator is in fact working" - because the group delay is constant? Do you think this is a criterion of a working integrator?

Comment: Well, I think it works because magnitude and phase shift match the 1/jω - criterion, at least if I fix the group delay which seems doable because it's constant.
I have to admit that much of my question describes something that's not directly related to my problem: why is the result distorted if I undo the time shift of the band limiter?